# Add a breakdown dimension to an SQL selection

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables look like this:

```
Year    Month   
--------------
2021     1     
2021     2   
2021     3     
2021     4   
2021     5      
2021     6
```

```
Planet
-------
Mercury
Venus
Earth
Mars
```

There is no relation between the two tables but i want to use them to create an SQL selection with a break down of the columns *Year* and *Month* based on the values of the table *Planet* like the following:

```
Year    Month   Planet
2021    1       Mercury
2021    1       Venus
2021    1       Earth
2021    1       Mars
2021    2       Mercury
2021    2       Venus
2021    2       Earth
2021    2       Mars
...
```

Since we cannot simply join the two table is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select *
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

You *could* also implement this using a regular `JOIN` but with a condition that is always true:

```
select *
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on 1=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

No join (cross join by default)

```
SELECT <* or your fields> FROM <t1>,<t2> ORDER BY <want you  want>
```